# enabling volume renaming in Quantal

Tags: partitioning, rename

I partitioned my vaio with ubuntu 12.10 (Simple Gnome environment) so that I have 2 separate volumes for folders and file keeping (call it a long paranoid windows using effect :)). These two volumes now act as mountable/unmountable volumes which is fine, still, wish there was a way to renaming them to my usual names (now they are named ”volume xGO”). However, renaming these volumes is disabled as an option on right click, so, if anyone knows how to solve this, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `disks` in `Dash`, and open the application which would open up a window showing all your storage devices. Click on the device on which your partition resided, and then select the partition which you want to rename. You can see a gear icon below the Volumes graph. Click on the `gear` and then on `Edit Filesystem Label...`, you can rename it to a valid name, please avoid using special characters except blank spaces, if you don't feel adventurous ;-)
[A similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103686/how-do-i-rename-a-usb-drive) has just been accepted by the asker. Please have a look.

Comment: thanks Jobin, however, being a n00b I finally got there this way:  apps/system utilities/preferences/disks. make sure the disks are unmounted, then select the partition you want to rename and click the ”more options” menu below the partitions list, then choose ”Edit Filesystem label”. rename the partition whatever you wish and you are done.